Why I am getting this error "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function..." when the function is not already declared
I keep getting this error "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function..." while trying to
declare a function.
It says the function is already declared but I can't see it anywhere.
Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Renaming the function is a straightforward solution.

Try it out:
if (!function_exists('your_function')) 
{
    function your_function()
 {
        /// your code here
  }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
